# Pragmatically Determine EXT JS 6 - Required or Uses subfile

Tags: javascript, optimization, extjs

***EXTJS 6, Requires or Uses - Determine programatically***

At work we are using EXT JS 6, I've been tasked with *'speeding it up'*.  I've already done several things and have achieved at least a 30% speed increase.  However when loading a page/module/section (whatever you want to call it), Every single component underneath the first is loaded async.
This is causing a measurable delay of about 20 seconds on a page load.

I believe this is because when we migrated from EXT JS 4, we kept everything in our class definitions as a requires.

```
requires: [
    'app.view.setup.thing.TabController',
    'app.view.setup.thing.Panel',
    'app.store.setup.combo.thingGroupIcons'
],
```

I've look at a lot of documentation and have come to the conclusion that we should be using 'uses' to define sections of the program that can load separately to the 'on-screen-first' stuff.

So for instance, the above would become something like:

```
requires: [
    'app.view.setup.thing.Panel',
],
uses: [
    'app.view.setup.thing.TabController',
    'app.store.setup.combo.thingGroupIcons'
],
```

The program probably has a good 500 pages/sections to it. Probably has 3000~ files. So my question is (really two fold).

**Question 1: How can I pragmatically determine if something in my 'requires' could/should be loaded using 'uses'**

and

***Question 2: Am I on the right track at all?***

There's a very hostile community around EXT JS, so I'm asking this question on Stack where I hope people will be more helpful.  I have spent seven hours so far today reading, and the below are some of the links that I think are actually helpful.

https://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-133191.html?s=8b90c637dd96fed53597cd029544d955
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.Class.html#cfg-requires

Comment: Btw regarding the whole 'speed up' thing. Do you use Sencha Cmd to compile your app and do you know about App Cache? https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/microloader.html#microloader_-_application_cache

Comment: Yes I do, and yes I do.  The compiled version is much faster (But still not fast enough), and the cache only makes a difference post download, which is after the current issue.

Comment: Are you sure you're using a built copy? If you're using a built copy, then this should not occur: "Every single component underneath the first is loaded async."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine which ones you can load via `uses`, you can only move everything from the "required" sections into the "uses" section, and check what's broken.

But with `uses`, you can only improve the loading time of the uncompiled version, not of the cmd compiled version, where all dependencies are in a single javascript file, and which should be the only version facing the customer.

Of course, you can always do the same as my boss did, and get some Highly Paid Consultants™ (from Sencha or a Sencha-approved outlet near you) to review your application. Their first result was exactly what I already told him: that there is no possibility to significantly improve the loading speed of our Cmd-compiled version further. They told us that we had only one option left - I should add an animated splash screen, which would cut down the loading time in half. It doesn't if you use a stop watch, of course, but the user does not have a stop watch when he starts the application...

Comment: Thank you this is a very good answer :) I'm guessing that moving everything into 'uses' from 'requires', then running 'sencha app build production' would list out the failures, or do you think I would have to test each modules functionality manually (Yea we don't have unit testing :-/)?  If the build command lists the errors I can probably write something using Regex to aid me in putting the right things in the right places...  Even if this does not change the size of the file being downloaded, it ***might*** let the JS run user side a little bit faster (Worth Testing)

Comment: You have to test manually. The build command, when building the dependency tree, doesn't care **when** the dependencies will be called, and the error will exhibit only at runtime.

Comment: Thanks that answers a lot of questions :)  Excellent Answer!